# SwiftUI Preview MPMediaItemArtwork

Tags: swiftui

I've got an array based on a structure that includes song title and artist as strings, and its artwork as type `MPMediaItemArtwork`. To get the preview to work in `Swift` UI I refer to

```
struct TrackRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TrackRow(track: Track(name: "Track 1", artist: "Artist 1", artwork: [MPMediaItemArtwork]))
    }
}
```

The view works fine when I've commented out the preview, and I've therefore been able to print to the console a selected `MPMediaItemArtwork` -- which is `MPConcreteMediaItemArtwork: 0x281efb890`. But it doesn't accept that either. What value can I put in for the preview artwork to make the preview provider work?

Extra Details:

```
struct Track: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var artist: String
    var artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork
}

func getTracks(chosenPlaylist: String) {
        trackArray = []
        for playlist in playlists! {
            if (playlist.value(forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)as! String) == chosenPlaylist {
                let songs = playlist.items
                            for song in songs {
                                if song.artwork != nil {
                                trackArray.append(Track(name: (song.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as! String), artist:(song.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as! String), artwork: song.artwork!))
                                }
                            }
                sortArray()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see what `artwork` and `MPMediaItemArtwork` looks like?

Comment: Just added the details for the struct of the array, and how I go about filling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I hadn't imported MediaPlayer, as I hadn't needed it for the view, but obviously did for preview view. The code that works is as follows:

```
struct TrackRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TrackRow(track: Track(name: "Track 1", artist: "Artist 1", artwork:MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Artwork"))))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `artwork` is an array of `MPMediaItemArtwork` so for the preview I would just grab the first item in the array like the following:

```
struct MPMediaItemArtwork {
   var name: String
}

struct Track {
    var name: String
    var artist: String
    var artwork: [MPMediaItemArtwork]
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(name: "0x281efb890")
    static var mediaArray: [MPMediaItemArtwork] = [artwork]

    static var previews: some View {
        TrackRow(track: Track(name: "Track 1", artist: "Artist 1", artwork: [mediaArray[0]]))
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not its own array though but rather part of the array as defined above. Also, the array is empty until the app properly runs and takes the music from the iOS device